# Jquery .get() result evaluation not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm relatively new to javascript, but I've read lots of posts talking about Jquery .get and the need to use a callback function today... but I guess I'm still not doing it right.  I have a function that 'gets' the result from a PHP page which accesses a MySQL table.

I've included alerts in my code so I can see that the page is called correctly and is returning the result I expect.  If the file already exists in the database then the 'get' returns "exists" if the file is in the database but flagged as deleted 'get' returns "deleted" and if the file isn't in the database 'get' returns nothing.

However, when I place alerts inside the `if(file_exists=="exists")` statement they never get triggered.  I even tried moving the entire evaluation section to another function and calling that function from inside the first. still no joy. `docReplace` never gets set to true and I never see the dialog asking if I want to replace it.

Please, some helpful suggestions?

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
function docCheck(){
    var attachfilepath = document.getElementById("AttachFile").value;
    var docguid = document.getElementById("DocGuid").value;
        //cut the file path down so just get the filename
    attachfile = attachfilepath.substr(attachfilepath.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);

    // Check to see if file exists. 

    $.get("Doc_Check.php", {guid:docguid, filename:attachfile}, function(file_exists){
        alert(file_exists);
        if(file_exists=="exists"){
            if(confirm("The file \"" + attachfile +"\" already exists.  Would you like to replace it?")){
                document.getElementById('docReplace').value = "true";
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else if(file_exists == "deleted"){
            document.getElementById('docReplace').value = "true";
        }   
    });
    var rreplace = document.getElementById('docReplace').value;
    alert (attachfile);
    alert (docguid);
    alert (rreplace);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `alert(attachfile)`, what contents does it show if you put it before the `if(confirm("The file \""...` instruction?

Comment: Is there any white space around the data returned?  Are you really getting just a plain string from Doc_Check.php?  No HTML?  JSON? XML?

Comment: Any alerts inside the if(file_exists=='exists') don't fire.  I don't think there's any white space. The line in the php file is (echo "exists")

Comment: *I don't think there's any white space.* ...Knowing it would be better than thinking it.

Comment: No whitespace - added this to be sure.  alert("Type: " + typeof file_exists + "<br>Contents:==>" + file_exists +"<== <br>Trim:==>" + $.trim(file_exists) + "<==");      Since posting this I've found a couple other people with the same issue - evaluating .get responses

Comment: You should probably echo the length of the string, not just print it out as line breaks won't show . . .